# Service progress updates

Tags: android, android-service

How can I get updates from a Service to an activity? For example, if I am downloading a file, I would like to show a progress bar in the activity.  I don't want to use AsyncTask (they only run while the activity is in focus, which is no good).

Many apps do this, so of course it is possible but finding an example is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I usually send a BroadcastIntent and register a BroadcastReceiver in my Activity